# Oracle Sql finding duplicates and selecting column value to pivot on this row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do you find duplicates based on some columns and get values that are not similar and add it to one line.

Basically

```
Last Name, House Number, Name, hobby
Scott,      100,         Peter, chess
Scott,      100,         John, scrabble
```

I want to now Create a temporary table and do this

```
Last Name, House Number, Name, Name2, hobby
Scott,     100,          Peter, John, chess
```

Note: There can be more than two names in the database. But we only want the chess/scrabble hobby pair. The temporary table should just have one hobby (associated with the first name but doesn't matter)the other can be inferred.

What is the most efficient way of doing this

This table can have about 100 million records to scroll through. (It is indexed by date and each date can have 100 million records). I feel pivoting might work but maybe too expensive?

Comment: Are there only two names that you care about?  A table has to have specific columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
select coalesce(t1.LastName, t2.LastName),
       coalesce(t1.HouseNumber, t2.HouseNumber),
       t1.Name, t2.Name, coalesce(t1.hobby, t2.hobby)
from (select * from tablename where hobby = 'chess') t1
full outer join
     (select * from tablename where hobby = 'scrabble') t2
  using (LastName,HouseNumber)
```